# RegisterHotKey not working for MediaPlayPause

Tags: c#, winforms, winapi, interop

The following code works fine:

```
public class HotKeys 
{
    [System.Runtime.InteropServices.DllImport("user32.dll")]
    public static extern bool RegisterHotKey(IntPtr hWnd, int id, int fsModifiers, int vk);
    [System.Runtime.InteropServices.DllImport("user32.dll")]
    public static extern bool UnregisterHotKey(IntPtr hWnd, int id);

    public enum KeyModifier
    {
        None = 0,
        Alt = 1,
        Control = 2,
        Shift = 4,
        WinKey = 8
    }
}
...

RegisterHotKey(this.Handle, id, (int)HotKeys.KeyModifier.None, (int)Keys.Add)
```

I can listen for a WndProc message for Msg 0x312 and I see that the hotkey "Add" was pressed even when my window doesn't have focus. I can see this message arrive in my app:

```
msg=0x312 (WM_HOTKEY) hwnd=0x4c19ee wparam=0x0 lparam=0x6b0000 result=0x0
```

If I simply change this to register Keys.MediaPlayPause, it no longer works from any application. No message is recieved at all when I press the key. But I think it's the right key because if I put focus on the window and press it, I log the following message:

```
msg=0x319 hwnd=0x4c19ee wparam=0x0 lparam=0xe0000 result=0x0
```

So the question is, why can't I register this specific key as a global hotkey? I already verified that it's not in use and the call to RegisterHotKey was successful.

Comment: IIRC the media keys are dispatched as wm_appcommands (0x319) rather than as key messages, you can check this by looking for key related messages if you mash the button on your focused window and comparing it with what you see with a non-media key

Answer (score 1):

MediaKeys are definitely treated differently. By capturing all keypresses, I was able to see the presses for media keys. This post worked for me:

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/toub/archive/2006/05/03/589423.aspx

Answer (score 1):

Media Keys can be quite tricky as they act quite differently than normal key presses, often differing from each manufacturer. Some keys will even translated into [`WM_APPCOMMAND` (0x0319)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms646275%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) messages to your window.

The best approach is to use a [low-level keyboard hook](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms644959%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) (`WH_KEYBOARD_LL`). This will require a little bit of P/Invoke code to get working, but you do not need an unmanaged C++ DLL.